# PDO Multiple insert failure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bind

Need some assistance here, being somewhat unfamiliar with PDO

I have a multiple insert

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->form_sql_table." (" . implode(",",$sql_arr_insert) . ") VALUES ".$sql_insert_placeholders.";";
```

This produses INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?)

The values array is

```
$arr_values = array(
[0] => array(
      [0] => 'value 1',
      [1] => 'value 2'
      ),
[1] => array(
      [0] => 'value 1',
      [1] => 'value 2'
      ),
[2] => array(
      [0] => 'value 1',
      [1] => 'value 2'
      )
);
```

Format array:

```
$arr_format = array(
  [0] => '?',
  [1] => '?'
);
```

Trying to bind these but keep getting the "number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" message

```
foreach($arr_values as $pkey => $parr){

  $values = array_values($parr);

  foreach ( $arr_format as $key => $bind ) {
    switch ($bind) {
    case '%d':
      $stmt->bindValue($key + 1, $values[$key], PDO::PARAM_INT);
      break;
    case '%s':
    default:
      $stmt->bindValue($key + 1, $values[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      // echo ($key + 1)." - ".$values[$key]."<br>";
      // prints out:
      // 1 - Value 1
      // 2 - Value 2
    }
   }

 }

 $stmt->execute();
```

I echo out the sql, looking fine, aswell as prin_r on arr_values and arr_format. It all seems to match.

Am i being really blind or is it something i have misunderstood on binding these ?

Hope someone can help me out here.. thanks

### SOLVED

Needed to index each occurrance of '?' starting from 1 to total number of '?'

Updated code:

```
if($multiarr){

    $count = 1;

        foreach($arr_values as $pkey => $parr){

            $values = array_values($parr);

            foreach ( $arr_format as $key => $val ) {
                switch ($values[$key]) {
                    case '%d':
                        $stmt->bindValue($count, $values[$key], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        break;
                    case '%s':
                    default:
                        $stmt->bindValue($count, $values[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }

                $count++;
            }
            }

            $stmt->execute();
     }
```

Comment: You'd be better off just inserting a single value set. With prepared statements, the efficiency gains from the non-standard multi-values version isn't as noticeable. prepare one statement, bind the variables, then just loop.

Comment: Been on the idea, but the host im using have a strict limit on number of insert/update querys pr hour, on max-limit sql insert is disabled for one hour. So on big inserts, like re-inserting big product catalogs etc i was looking for a way to do batch inserts in one query like ive previously done with old fashion mysql_query to get around this limitation

Comment: There are 6 placeholders so you have to bind 6 values before calling execute. Also the `$key` always starts at 0 with each inner loop which is wrong.

Comment: okay, sorted it out after a breath of fresh air. Needed to index each occurrance of '?' with numbers from 1 to total number of '?'. tried to post updated code but i am unable to do so within the first 8 hours... Ill add it in original post

Comment: you should consider posting  your solution as answer and accept :) thanks